# Resize all images in a subdirectory

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing

I have a directory named TRAIN, and it has 37 subdirectoris which contains images of different size, I wanted to load those images with TensorFlow's ImageDataGenerator, but it needs images of same size. I want to add padding to those images to resize them.

```
  tf.image.resize_with_crop_or_pad(
    image, target_height, target_width
)
```

I found this above code on internet but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: No. ``ImageDataGenerator`` does not expect all the images in the same size. You can specify output size by ``target_size=(width, height)`` argument in your generator.

Comment: So, if one of my image is, let's say, (230, 300), and if I specify the target_size=(400, 400), will it stretch the image to (400,400) or it will add padding ? @Kaveh

Comment: It will use of ``nearest`` method which is the default value of ``interpolation``. You can use other methods if you wish. check this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resize the images from the directories using `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory`.
Mention the required image size in `image_size=(img_height, img_width)`. Default image_size will be (256,256)
Find the below sample code

```
import tensorflow as tf
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```